# Elites saying "Buddhism is a child of Hinduism."

Tags: history, dharma, vivekananda, buddhism, saint

Experts and Elite Personalities of Sanatana Dharma knows that Buddhism is born from Hinduism but do not agree with some teachings of Hinduism.

Swami Vivekananda is an elite personality states this fact.:

> There were many names for many parts of the organs, because they had to*
> cut up animals for sacrifice. The sea is described as full of ships.
> Sea voyage was prohibited later on, partly because there came the fear
> that people might thereby become Buddhists.
>
> **Buddhism was the rebellion of newly-formed Kshatriyas against Vedic
> priestcraft.**
>
> Hinduism threw away Buddhism after taking its sap. The attempt of all
> the Southern Acharyas was to effect a reconciliation between the two.
> Shankaracharya's teaching shows the influence of Buddhism. His
> disciples perverted his teaching and carried it to such an extreme
> point that some of the later reformers were right in calling the
> Acharya's followers "crypto-buddhists".
>
> What is Spencer's unknowable? It is our Maya. Western philosophers are
> afraid of the unknowable, but our philosophers have taken a big jump
> into the unknown, and they have conquered.
>
> Western philosophers are like vultures soaring high in the sky, but
> all the while, with their eye fixed on the carrion beneath. They
> cannot cross the unknown, and they therefore turn back and worship the
> almighty dollar.
>
> There have been two lines of progress in this world—political and
> religious. In the former the Greeks are everything, the modern
> political institutions being only the development of the Grecian; in
> the latter the Hindus are everything.
>
> My religion is one of which Christianity is an offshoot and **Buddhism a
> rebel child.**
>
> [[Notes Taken Down In Madras, 1892-93,...,The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda]](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_6/Notes_Of_Class_Talks_And_Lectures/Notes_Taken_Down_In_Madras,_1892-93)

Are there any similar statements from other such elite personalities of Sanatana Dharma saying that Buddhism is a child of Hinduism.?

Comment: Buddha is one of the avatars of Vishnu. so yeah, it is a child of Hinduism. Buddhism, along with Jainism, Charvaka etc. form the nastik schools of thought.

Comment: As per the Vaishnava faith, it is a heretical doctrine expounded upon by Vishnu to delude Daityas. However, all Sramana faiths arouse out of skepticism of Vedas, so their cause is the Vedas in a sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think this really depends on ones perspective I know little about Hinduism (Im here to learn) but I am a Theravadian Buddhist. One thing about Buddhism is the rejection of many core Hindu ideas from the Vedas to anatta, the difference in the idea of karma nibbana vs moksha and etc.. I would guess it depends on one stance toward those ideas and the philosophical schools. Though there certainly is a relation between them, not such a distinct family like relation found in abrahamic religions but never the less related. Though I think the Buddha would reject the notion itself, personally I kinda like it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I disagree there is a clear connection to the faiths and the skepticism of the Vedas led to Buddhism being an offshoot, but NOT in the sense of a separate emanation or limb of the Vedic faith. I guess cause is a better word here.

Comment: I think the issue here is the idea of Hinduism as it exists today. Buddhism is a breakaway from Brahaminism and other ascetic beliefs and religions at the time. Brahaminism is not Hinduism; very much like modern Judaism is not 1st temple judaism or 2nd temple, and in the case of Hinduism brahaminism is and ever bigger gulf in practice and beliefs. It seems modern Hinduism is also influence by Buddhism, Neo-Platonism, and various local beliefs. Hinduism as we see it today formed over the last few thousand years, but it certainly buddhism rejected and adopted beliefs from brahaminsm.

Comment: In all the major religions of the world there is a cross pollination of ideas and influences rejecting or accepting ideas of the surrounding religions and beliefs. As well as a continual change and adaptation. Its way more complicated but part of the issue not addressed is Hindu nationalism trying to adopt buddhism, even after it had been basically eradicated from India by the 9th century. Early Buddhism is definitely a religion from India and its ideas and beliefs are a product of its time after that ideas get cross pollinated mixed and ect. Plus there is more than one "Buddhism" to consider.

Answer (score 1):

The philosopher and later President of India, Dr. Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan said in his *Indian Philosophy (1923)*, "Early Buddhism is not an absolutely original doctrine" and that "Buddhism, in its origin at least, is an offshot of Hinduism". Also the current Dalai Lama who is the spiritual leader of Tibetan Buddhists has said that the Buddha was born in a Hindu family. Now to be fair the Dalai Lama did not say Buddhism was an offshot of Hinduism but he did acknowledge that the Buddha was born and raised in a Hindu environment and so I think it's fair to say that it must've had at least some influence on his teachings.

Comment: There was no such thing as hinduism before Buddhism, call it vedic or brahmanism

Comment: That's what a couple of academics in the West who have been saying this for the last 20 years or so. But the general view remains that Hinduism dates back to the Vedic period, if not even earlier to the Harappan period.

Comment: yes, i agree with them. it's a retrofit.  my feeling is that hinduism is vedanta, and moreover, as mentioned many times, buddhism does not revolve around god

Comment: i would also argue that swami vivekananda's idea was to defend against british imperial thought, i.e., a system attempting to further divide indians

Comment: @blue_ego Hinduism is a distorted version of Vedanta or Hindu polytheism propounded by Vivekananda the proper term is Vedic religion or Vedic dharma which includes all 6 Astika darshanas Minamasa, Samkhya, Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Yoga and Vedanta.